# How to narrow (cast) down an erased type to an intersection type in scala?

Tags: scala, casting, pattern-matching

Consider:

```
trait Base
trait Derived extends Base

class Narrow[T<:Base](arg :T) {
    val d = arg match {
        case derived :Derived => Some(derived)
        case _ => None
    }
}
```

In previous versions of scala (before 2.11.8) I remember `derived` to have the type of `T with Derived`. This sometimes caused unexpected behaviour of type inference, but provided full information. Now (in 2.11.8), `derived` within the `case` clause is of type simply `Derived`. This is of course a simplified example, but in reality I have a method accepting a `T with Derived` and I wonder if it is possible to safely (and without compiler warnings) obtain a reference to such an instance? Naturally,

```
case derived :Derived with T =>
```

produces warning about unchecked (erased) type matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case derived: Derived with T @unchecked` works. Of course, using `@unchecked` means you must make sure the code is safe instead of the compiler, but in this case I think it's as safe as it was before 2.11.8 (i.e. thanks to type erasure clients can pass arguments which aren't actually `T`).

Comment: A bit of a gordian knot solution... But since it looks like what I really wanted isn't possible, probably the best one.

Answer (score 0):

Since **pattern match** with **generic** will be erased by compiler in compile time and all match **clauses** will match the **superclass**: `Derived`

Maybe [TypeTag](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) is a better solution for this scenario:

```
class Narrow[T <: Base](arg: T)(implicit typeTag: TypeTag[T]) {
  val d = arg match {
    case derived if typeTag.tpe =:= typeOf[Derived] => println("I am ")
    case derived if typeTag.tpe <:< typeOf[Derived] => println("Hello")
    case _ => println("world")
  }
}
```

1. only match type: `Derived` firstly, actual type: `Derived` matched without `Derived` subclass type
2. match `Derived` subclass type(that `Derived with T` or `T extends Derived`, narrow it), since `Derived` type has matched in the **clause 1**, this clause will not match `Derived` type now
3. match other classes.

Comment: 1 and 2 are wrong: these match depending on static type, not on class.